# Dictionary creation code. What is going on here most likely?

Tags: python

I am looking at this code:

```
DICT_IDS = dict(x.split('::') 
                for x in object.method()        
                ['ids_comma_separated'].split(','))
DICT_ATTRS = dict(x.split('::') 
                  for x in object.method()                     
                  ['comma_separated_key_value_pairs'].split(','))
```

So each constanty will ultimately refer to a dictionary, but what is going on inside the constructors?

Does this occur first:

```
x.split('::') 
for x in object.method()
```

So `x` must be a string that is split on the `::`? right?

**EDIT**

Oh....

```
 for x in object.method()       
 ['ids_comma_separated'].split(',')
```

is executed first. `x` is probably another dictionary that we key into using `ids_comma_separated` whose value is a string that needs to be split on the `,` like `"cat,dog, mouse"` into a list. So x is going to be a list?

Comment: `x` is something (likely a `str`) that has a `split` method; it's definitely not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just parsing values like this into a dict:

```
'ids_comma_separated': "somekey::somevalue,anotherkey::anothervalue"
```

from a method (`object.method()`) that returns a dictionary:

```
class object:
    def method():
        return {
            'ids_comma_separated': "somekey::somevalue,anotherkey::anothervalue"
        }

DICT_IDS = dict(x.split('::') 
                for x in object.method()        
                ['ids_comma_separated'].split(','))
DICT_IDS
# {'somekey': 'somevalue', 'anotherkey': 'anothervalue'}
```

The part inside the `dict()` is a generator comprehension but the line breaks make it a little hard to see that:

```
(x.split('::') for x in object.method()['ids_comma_separated'].split(','))
```

in each iteration `x` is `somekey::somevalue` which gets split once again.

Comment: Oh I see, x is going to be `somekey::somevalue` and `anotherkey::anothervalue`

Comment: @Jwan622 yes, exactly.